# Which is a linear and homogeneous recurrence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

Which of the following choices is a linear and homogenous recurrence?

$1)$ $A_n = A_{n-1} + 4A_{n-2} + 3n$

$2)$ $A_n = n + 1$

$3)$ $A_n = (A_{n-1})^2$

$4)$ $A_n = 5A_{n-1} + A_{n-2} + 3A_{n-3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is a linear homogeneous recurrence relation?

It is an equation of the form: $A_0a_n + A_1a_{n-1} + A_2a_{n-2} + ... + A_ka_{n-k} = 0$

Indeed, the equation above is of order k.

For it to be linear, there should be no powers greater than $1$ lying around the recurrence relation terms. It is easy to verify this for your equations.

Now, important to note is the right-hand side of the equation. Homogeneous recurrence relations simply are equations which have all terms which define the recurrence relation on one side and on the other side there is only $0$, ergo, the recurrence relation equates to $0$. Non-homogeneous recurrence relations equate to a function $f(n)$ and not to $0$. Try shift the terms of the equations around and see what you get.

What does this tell you about the homogeneity of the equations you have been given?

Comment: Okay so that rules out answer choices 2 and 3. I would say that the answer is #4 however the second term is missing a coefficient of 4?

Comment: I would say both 1 and 4. What difference do the constant co-efficients make?

Comment: The answer was #4. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Excuse my previous comment, I meant to say just 4. Of course, 1 is not homogeneous at all since $f(n) = 3n$ exists.

Happy to help!